# UIToolbar-button disappears when adding flexible psace

Tags: ios, uitoolbar

I cant put by UIToolbar-item in the right side of the screen, because the it disappears.

If I lay it out like this, the button is visible:

[image]

But when I change it to this - the button is not visible when starting the simulator.

[image]

Any ideas? Dont really know where to start.

Comment: Did you check that the width of the toolbar does not exceed the width of the superview ?

Comment: Whow. That was easy. How could I not think of that. I just set a constraint to have equal widths on the rootview and the UIToolbar.. Thanks! Feel free to make it an answer.